# White area at the bottom of the chart

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I use mschart in my website and I have a problem with that.
After I show the chart, a white area at the bottom of the chart will display.

That's not a part of my chart. What is that and how do I remove it?
Here is my MSChart Code.

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Palette="SeaGreen" RightToLeft="No">
                <Titles>
                    <asp:Title ShadowColor="32, 0, 0, 0" Font="Tahoma, 12pt," ShadowOffset="2" Text="Operation"
                        ForeColor="26, 59, 105">
                    </asp:Title>
                </Titles>
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueType="Auto" ChartType="Bar">
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        <AxisX2 TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt">
                        </AxisX2>
                        <AxisY LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" TitleFont="Tahoma, 12pt" Title="totalScore">
                            <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64"></MajorGrid>
                            <LabelStyle Font="Tahoma, 12pt" />
                            <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                        </AxisY>
                        <AxisX LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" Interval="1" TitleFont="Tahoma, 12pt" IsLabelAutoFit="True"
                             Title="" LineWidth="1">
                            <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64"></MajorGrid>
                            <LabelStyle Font="Tahoma, 12pt" />
                            <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                        </AxisX>
                        <AxisY2 TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt">
                        </AxisY2>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: You should really show pictures or something. I doubt anybody is going to know what you're talking about otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found my answer by myself.
in cs , i define an area that was unnecessary and because of that,MSChart draw an empty area chart, bottom of my true area chart.